# Change GeoServer listener IP address / Port

Tags: apache, postgis, ubuntu-18.04, geoserver

I have an installed GeoServer on a DigitalOcean Droplet. I am developing a Leaflet based web app, which uses WFS Transactions through GeoServer to do CRUD operations in a direction to a PostGIS database.

I would like to change GeoServer's listener to just listen to the same origin (eg. for a webpage on the same server) but not the whole internet, because now anybody can load, modify data if knows my geoserver url and the layernames.

I tried to set up the GeoServer user settings, but i can't add user authentication to the WFS Transactions in Leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

go to `C:\Program Files\GeoServer 2.7.0\etc\jetty.xml` to add of change the relevant `<Connector>` element. Of course, you can only listen on the configured IP address or addresses of your computer's network interface / interfaces